Why is the function fib2 much faster than the functions fib and fib3?
The following C code, why is the function fib2 much faster than the functions fib and fib3?
compile: gcc -O3 main.c -o main
gcc version:
gcc (GCC) 10.2.1 20200825 (Alibaba 10.2.1-3.6 2.32)
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE

output:
102334155   fib Time spent: 0.185822 seconds
1059467309  fib2 Time spent: 0.036215 seconds  // why faster?
102334155   fib3 Time spent: 0.181988 seconds

Code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

long long fib2(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
    {
        return n;
    }
    else
    {
        long long first = fib2(n - 1);
        long long second = fib2(n - 2);
        return first * first + second * second;
    }
}

int fib(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
    {
        return n;
    }
    else
    {
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
    }
}

long long fib3(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
    {
        return n;
    }
    else
    {
        long long first = fib3(n - 1);
        long long second = fib3(n - 2);
        return first + second;
    }
}

void main()
{
    clock_t start1 = clock();
    printf("%d", fib(40));
    clock_t end1 = clock();
    double time_spent1 = (double)(end1 - start1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("fib Time spent: %f seconds\n", time_spent1);
    printf("%d", fib2(40));
    clock_t end2 = clock();
    double time_spent2 = (double)(end2 - end1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("fib2 Time spent: %f seconds\n", time_spent2);
    printf("%d", fib3(40));
    clock_t end3 = clock();
    double time_spent3 = (double)(end3 - end2) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("fib3 Time spent: %f seconds\n", time_spent3);
}


The calculations are different; the comparison isn't fair.  That said, I'm not sure why there's a speedup.

Please eliminate the UBs such as signed overflow and wrong formatter for printf, although I don't really think the speedup is due to it.

You have undefined behavior in your code. Everything can happen. The UB is also in the overflow of the arithmetic inside the fib functions.

fib2(10) already causes UB. And the compiler will use this to produce some crazy code which works if there's no UB. So probably you will fall in a case which causes an early termination.

It is not your question but fib2 in your question looks suspiciously like the multiplicative version of the fibonacci recursion, except for the fact it is done on (n+1)/2/(n+1)/2-1, not on n-1/n-2. That would also have made fib2 faster, but this time because n is reduced to 0 or 1 in log(n) recursions.

Analysis of the generated assembly code shows the compiler partially expands the recursive calls in fib2, and this reduces the number of recursive calls by a factor over 800 for the n = 40 case.
For n above 1, the C code nominally computes fib2(n) by calling fib2(n-1) and fib2(n-2). The generated code handles n up to 3 with fixed return values, after which it computes fib2(n) from call for fib2(n-3), fib2(n-4), fib2(n-5), and fib2(n-6). (This is seen by manually tracing the generated code.) While this is four calls from one fib2(n) call, it skips down two levels of recursion. Below is code that tells us about the effect of that by counting the numbers of recursive calls made:
#include <stdio.h>


//Count calls made by original recursion.
long long fibx(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 1 + fibx(n-1) + fibx(n-2);
}


// Count calls made by optimized code.
long long fiby(int n)
{
    if (n <= 3)
        return 1;
    else
        return 1 + fiby(n-3) + fiby(n-4) + fiby(n-5) + fiby(n-6);
}


int main(void)
{
    printf("%lld\n", fibx(40));
    printf("%lld\n", fiby(40));
}

This shows 331,160,281 calls for the original code and 386,393 for the optimized code! While the optimized code has additional arithmetic per call (to combine the results calculated from the various calls), it clearly eliminates a great deal of repetitive work.
This explains why fib2 is so fast. It does not address why fib and fib3 remain slow. I have not analyzed their code yet, although, interestingly, each contains only one recursive call—but it is in a loop, so the routine executes some number of recursive calls. That seems like it would be interesting to investigate.
Also, I only analyzed the code generated for the external entry point to fib2. The compiler also generates a special fib2.part.0 version of the routine that is called by main. It does some things of its own before (sometimes) calling fib2. Further, the compiler inlined one recursive call into main; it does not call fib2.part.0(40) but rather calls fib2.part.0(39) and fib2.part.0(38) and calculates the sum of their squares.
In any case, it seems clear the performance difference is due to optimization choices made by the compiler.

The comparison between these three processing functions was unfair from the beginning. For example, when I tested with the 40th Fibonacci number, the results were completely reversed (fib2 had a longer processing time).
102334155  fib Time spent: 0.401000 seconds
1059467309 fib2 Time spent: 0.815000 seconds
102334155  fib3 Time spent: 0.423000 seconds

On the other hand, in my opinion, calculations on larger numbers will cause longer processing times:

Between the fib and fib3 functions, the calculation time will be the same if the result is a small Fibonacci number within the int range. However, if the number is larger, fib will only produce an int result, while fib3 returns a long long type, which requires more computational work.

It is impossible to compare fib2 with fib and fib3 because their recursive formulas are different; fib2 always uses more calculations. It might be because the result after each calculation of fib2, due to frequent overflows, is much smaller, so the processing time seems faster, but this is, of course, just an illusion.



On my machine, fib2 is still the fastest.
102334155 fib Time spent: 0.185822 seconds
1059467309 fib2 Time spent: 0.036215 seconds
102334155 fib3 Time spent: 0.181988 seconds


I stick to my statement that approximately 100% of all benchmarking questions on SO can be explained by incorrect benchmarking rather than the algorithms themselves...
Ignoring overflows and the choice of benchmarking method, then this is still incorrect for the following reasons:

You have stdio.h console I/O in the middle of the benchmarking code. end2 - end1 as well as end3 - end2 at best measures the time from where the first benchmark started, plus the time it took to do all console I/O for printing that result, plus the actual benchmarking time of the function. That's a completely irrelevant measurement no matter what result you happened to get.

On a x86 PC there's a whole lot of stuff going on such as "cache warming" = relevant data has to be loaded into cache, as well as context switches where the OS simply lets something else execute for a while, which could happen in the middle of your benchmarking.
Furthermore, an optimizing compiler can take advantage of previous code and calculations from the first test when generating the code for the next test, making the tests completely unfair. The cache can also benefit from a previous calculation having loaded the data into cache for the next one.
For these reason it is never correct to do benchmarking of several different algorithms in sequence from within the same program. Instead execute them as 3 different stand-alone tests (with #ifdef compiler switches or the like).


Also notably, making these functions static would improve the compiler's ability to perform inlining and tail call optimization a lot, without changing the contents of the functions.
